# JavaScript sound synthesis

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a third level project I am going to attempt to build a web based sound synthesiser using HTML5 and JavaScript.

Does anyone know of any APIs that would allow me to deploy it on all or most browsers?

I have so far seen an API that works with Firefox only and another on GitHub that works with Chrome only.

It would be great to be able to use this in Safari, as with the iPad it could become a stand alone instrument.
Is this feasible?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to http://caniuse.com they will tell you if a technology is supported by Safari or not. Go check it out. Then, any API that you use will tell you what support you will get for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be to do it server side. I would have your app use AJAX to call a server-side script to generate the sound file if it doesn't already exist, then return it's URL so you can use it in JS. Eventually, all the different sound files should be created by the server and named properly allowing you to look them up quickly.

Answer (score 1):

http://mohayonao.github.com/timbre.js/ seems pretty powerful. Pity some of the documentation appears to be in Japanese only!

Answer (score 0):

WebPd is a partial Puredata port to JS - https://github.com/sebpiq/WebPd - it works well with Chrome and Firefox. *"It is also a standalone DSP library. Every object as you know it in Pure Data exposes a complete API, allowing developers to control everything with JavaScript."*